# Why Would Jquery / Ajax alert(data) work but not .html(data)

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, httpresponse

I'm trying to create a table dynamically based on users selects with jquery / ajax / php

I believe I am close but can't nail down this last issue..

I am receiving a correct alert data but it will not write itself into the specified div layer.

I am not a jquery expert, so any help at newbie level would be very much appreciated.

THE HTML / Jquery

```
     <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
     </head>

     <div class="formtaglong">
     <input type="radio" value="both" name="buildings" class="small_radio" checked > <span class="checkboxText">Both</span> 
     <input type="radio" value="thunder" name="buildings" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Thunderhawk</span> 
     <input type="radio" value="center" name="buildings" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Center Drive</span> 
     </div>
     <div class="formtaglong" id="checkall">
      <input type="checkbox" value="All" id="sa" name="sa" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">All</span>
     <?php
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
             echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['operator'].'" name="users[]" class="small_radio"> <span class="checkboxText">' .$row['operator'] . '</span> ';
         }
         ?>
     </div>

     <div class="formtaglong">
     <input type="radio" id="alltime" value="alltime" name="daterange" class="small_radio" checked ><span class="checkboxText">All</span>
     <input type="radio" id="today" value="today" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Today</span>
     <input type="radio" id="yesterday" value="yesterday" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">Yesterday</span>
     <input type="radio" id="threedays" value="threedays" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">3 Days</span>
     <input type="radio" id="thisweek" value="thisweek" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">This Week</span>
     <input type="radio" id="thismonth" value="thismonth" name="daterange" class="small_radio" > <span class="checkboxText">This Month</span>
     <input type="Submit" name="print" id="print" value="Submit" class="button">
     </div>
     <div class="results" id="results">
    <!-- THE RESULTS SHOULD BE DYNAMICALLY POSTED HERE -->
     </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#checkall").click(function() {

                //check radio buildings for selected value
                var radBuild = $('input:radio[name=buildings]:checked').val();

                //check radio daterange for selected value
                var radDate = $('input:radio[name=daterange]:checked').val();

                //create array for multiple possibilites from checkbox users
                var chkUsers = [];
                //loop through checkboxes appending values to array
                $('#checkall :checked').each(function() {
                   chkUsers.push($(this).val());
                 });

                 //send the request
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/inventory/pick-print-results.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: "buildings=" + radBuild + "&daterange=" + radDate + "&users[]=" + chkUsers,
                    // callback for success
                     success: function(data, textStatus) {
                         $(".results").html(data);  //No data here
                          alert(data); //Data here

                      }, //end success else...
                      //if failsauce success throw error
                      error: function() {
                          alert('Not OKay');
                         } //end error failsauce
                      }); //ends .ajax function
                   }); //end #checkall. click function
                }); // ends ready function
                </script>
```

The Alert Popup is returning valid html.. my popup on click has data like this..

```
<table border="1px" style="width: 761px;" cellspadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="tr2center"><td>AS001-70S</td><td>10-9-12, 9:42 am</td><td>Don Ford </td><td>500</td><td>LOAD</td><td>09-28-2010</td><td> 

                <a href="picking.php?radiopart=1005">Mark Picked</a></td></tr><tr class="tr1center"><td>H-016-V75</td><td>10-9-12, 11:28 am</td><td>Don Ford </td><td>80</td><td>LOAD</td><td>09-05-2012</td><td> 

                <a href="picking.php?radiopart=4503">Mark Picked</a></td></tr></table>
```

My php processing page...

```
<?php 
include 'connect_to_db.php';
if(isset($_POST['daterange'])){ $daterange = $_POST['daterange']; }else{$daternage='';}
if(isset($_POST['users'])) { $users=$_POST['users']; }else{ $users='';}
if(isset($_POST['buildings'])){ $buildings=$_POST['buildings']; }else{$buildings='';}

//Build Daterange AND statment for query
switch ($daterange) {
    case "alltime":
    $query_chunk_2='';
    break;
    case "today":
    $query_chunk_2= 'AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d') . '\'';
    break;
    case "yesterday":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    case "threedays":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-3 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    case "thisweek":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    case "thismonth":
    $query_chunk_2='AND pi.date_requested >= \'' . date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-30 days')) . '\'';
    break;
    default:
    $query_date='';
}

//Build Building AND Statment for query
switch ($buildings) {
    case "both":
    $query_chunk_3='';
    break;
    case "center":
    $query_chunk_3='AND l.building LIKE \'%Center%\'';
    break;
    case "thunder":
    $query_chunk_3='AND l.building LIKE \'%Thunder%\'';
    break;
    default:
    $query_chunk_3='';
}

//check if users is array
if(is_array($users)) {
//Deal With User Array
 //IF ALL IS SET..... GET ALL USERS IGNORE OTHER SELECTIONS
if($_POST['users'][0]=='All' || $_POST['users'][0]=='All,') {
    $query_chunk_4="AND  o.operator NOT LIKE ' '";
} else {
    //ELSE WE LOOP THROUGH EACH VALUE AND BUILD THE QUERY STATEMENT

    //Chunk 4 segment 1
    $query_chunk_4 ="AND o.operator IN(";

    //Get Total Array Values To Properly Add Commas to the String
    $i=0; // zero start value counter
    $ar_count=count($_POST['users']); //total elments in array
        foreach($_POST['users'] as $k=>$c)
        {
            $query_chunk_4.="'".$c."'";
            if($i!=$ar_count && $i!=($ar_count-1)){
                $query_chunk_4.=",";
            }
            $i++;
        }
        //Chunk 4 last segment
        $query_chunk_4 .=")";
}
}else { //USERS IS NOT AN ARRAY
$query_chunk_4="AND  o.operator NOT LIKE ' '";
}

//STATIC BEGINING OF QUERY
$query_chunk_1="SELECT pi.* , p.part_number, o.description, l.location, r.received_date
FROM picks AS pi
INNER JOIN parts AS p ON p.part_id = pi.part_id
INNER JOIN operators AS o ON o.operator_id = pi.operator_id
INNER JOIN locations AS l ON l.location_id = pi.location_id
INNER JOIN received AS r ON r.received_id = pi.received_id
WHERE pi.action_id = '11'";

//STATIC END OF QUERY
$query_chunk_last="ORDER BY pi.date_requested ASC";

//MERGE QUERY
$big_chunk_sql=$query_chunk_1 . ' ' . $query_chunk_2 . ' ' . $query_chunk_3 . ' ' . $query_chunk_4 . ' ' . $query_chunk_last;
$big_chunk_query=mysql_query($big_chunk_sql) or die(mysql_error());
//echo "<br> Big Chunk  = ".$big_chunk_sql;

        $i='';
        echo  '<table border="1px" style="width: 761px;" cellspadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($big_chunk_query)) {
           if ($i%2 !=0)
             $rowColor = 'tr1center';
              else
             $rowColor = 'tr2center';
                $pendingdate= trim($data['received_date']);
                $newpendingdate = date('m-d-Y',strtotime($pendingdate));
                echo '<tr class="'.$rowColor.'"><td>'.$data['part_number'] . '</td><td>'.date("m-j-y, g:i a", strtotime($data['date_requested'])) .'</td><td>'
                .$data['description'].'</td><td>'. $data['qty_requested'] . '</td><td>'. $data['location'].'</td><td>'. $newpendingdate . '</td><td> 
                <a href="picking.php?radiopart='.urlencode($data['org_transaction_id']) .'">Mark Picked</a></td></tr>';
                if($data['notes_to_picker']!='') { 
                echo '<tr class="'.$rowColor.'" align="center"><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td><td align="right"><b>notes:</b></td><td colspan="4">' . $data['notes_to_picker'].'</td></tr>';
                }
                $i++;
            }
            echo '</table>';
?>
```

EDIT With Changing the $('.results').html(data) to $('.results').text(data) I get exactly this in my div, it looks like html code wrapped in pre tags exactly as it appears on this page..

```
<table border="1px" style="width: 761px;" cellspadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="tr2center"><td>AS001-70S</td><td>10-9-12, 9:42 am</td><td>Don Ford </td><td>500</td><td>LOAD</td><td>09-28-2010</td><td> <a href="picking.php?radiopart=1005">Mark Picked</a></td></tr><tr class="tr1center"><td>H-016-V75</td><td>10-9-12, 11:28 am</td><td>Don Ford </td><td>80</td><td>LOAD</td><td>09-05-2012</td><td> <a href="picking.php?radiopart=4503">Mark Picked</a></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Mkae sure your `$('.results')` selector is actually selecting something.

Comment: What does `$(".results").text(data);` display?

Comment: @dunc resullts.text(data) actually writes the html as text into the correct div layer.. so it looks like my alert does with the `<pre>` tags

Comment: If `text` works but `html` doesn't, that suggests to me that you have some malformed HTML in your Ajax response that the browser is failing to parse. (Or, it is getting parsed, but the result is rendered in a non-visible way. Use Firebug or other tool to check if the HTML is being added to the `results` element.)

Comment: Could you update your OP with exactly the contents of `$(".results").text(data);`?

Comment: @aspillers that appears to be the issue! I just tried to copy + paste the alert into the div manually and it would not parse. I'll comb through it. I just figured since I'm weak at jquery that would be where my issue was. Thanks to all 3 of you for the help.

Comment: @dunc I added the edit above, I'm going through the html now to see what the problem is.

Comment: I can't see any issues with your HTML. Are you using Chrome/FireFox? If so, can you DOM-inspect the resultant HTML of the `$.text()` command? I'm wondering if maybe your HTML has been `htmlspecialchars` encoded or something - i.e. it's not actually HTML at all, just characters?

Comment: @dunc I'm currently using firefox and it appears the issue was with the div results not the actual results from the php page. Again thank you for the time it helps to have those extra eyes and input.

Comment: I'd recommend answering your own question, with an explanation, so that other users can quickly and easily see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the original html not the result html.
my container had invalid html inside it, but removing that the html was displayed properly.